# How to use 'go to path' with aliases in Visual Studio Code

Tags: javascript, vue.js, visual-studio-code, alias

Using Visual Studio Code, I can go open a file that I am importing using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + click into the import declaration:

[image: Go to file using Visual Studio Code CTRL + click]

By doing that the Visual Studio Code will open the file *index.js* at the folder *./code*

I also can create and export alias to some files using *vue.config.js*:

[image: Exporting alias for files using vue.config.js]

Then I can import using the alias:

[image: Importing using the alias]

The problem I want to solve is: How can I <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + click and open a file that were imported using alias?

There are any extensions that can do it?

It would be very useful, because when I need to edit the file I could go directly to it without having to manually look for the path.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can configure the path aliases in VS Code with a [`jsconfig.json` file](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig) (or `tsconfig.json` if using TypeScript).

Create `<projectRoot>/jsconfig.json` with the [`compilerOptions.paths` option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#paths) set to glob patterns that match the ones from Webpack's `resolve.alias`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "@themeConfig": ["src/libs/themeConfig.js"],
      "@core/*": ["src/@core/*"],
      "@validations": ["src/@core/utils/validations/validations.js"],
      "@axios/*": ["src/libs/axios/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

[image: screencast]

Comment: I would give this answer a 100 points if I could. Merci!

Comment: De rien  